# JsessionID decoding date extracting

Tags: java, web, decoding, jsessionid

I am looking for someone who could decode the following JSessionID for me

```
jsessionid =  D6E26A03B27ACD980CD95A1D6A1C8AA5
```

I need to extract the date out of it (probably 30 March 2009 as far as I remember)
to prove that I connected that day on that server.
One fix and identifiable value should be 195.25.216.217 (IP address of the server)

Comment: Session IDs are random nonces and do not contain any actual data.

Comment: What app server are you using?

Answer (score 4):

As [SLaks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/34397/slaks) pointed out, session ids are not generated according to any standards, for most application servers. You are better off checking your **web server logs** for that IP address logged around that time.